# Why isn't Webpack excluding a folder I specified?

Tags: typescript, webpack, definitelytyped

I keep my server & client code in the same repository, though I use Webpack to build only the client:

[image]

My project builds fine if I delete the src/server folder. But when it's there I get all these Webpack Typescript duplicate definition errors like:

```
[1m[31mERROR in /home/rje/projects/ekaya/typings/main/ambient/react-dom/index.d.ts
(70,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
```

which are caused by Webpack trying to build one of the files in my server folder that contains:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/main.d.ts" />
```

**How can I get Webpack to completely ignore the server folder?**

I've tried in my webpack.config.js:

```
var rootPath = __dirname; 
var srcPath = path.join(rootPath, 'src/client');
var distPath = path.join(rootPath, 'dist/client');
var serverPath = path.join(rootPath, 'src/serve
...
loaders:
        [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory', include: [srcPath], exclude: [serverPath]},
            {test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory', include: [srcPath], exclude: [serverPath] },
            {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader?cacheDirectory', include: [srcPath], exclude: [serverPath] },
            {test: /\.tsx$/, loader: 'ts-loader?cacheDirectory', include: [srcPath], exclude: [serverPath] },
```

Here's the full webpack config if it helps:

```
//https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html

var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');
var rootPath = __dirname; // e.g.  ~/projects/ekaya
var srcPath = path.join(rootPath, 'src/client');
var distPath = path.join(rootPath, 'dist/client');
var serverPath = path.join(rootPath, 'src/server');

module.exports =
{
    bail: true,
    cache: false,
    context: rootPath,
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map', //inline-source-map, https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
    target: 'web', //node, web
    devServer:
    {
        contentBase: distPath,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        outputPath: path.join(distPath, 'devServer')
    },
    entry:
    {
        app: path.join(srcPath, 'app/home.jsx'),
        lib: ['react', 'react-router', 'react-dom', 'jquery', 'lodash', 'history']
    },
    output:
    {
        path: distPath,
        publicPath: '',
        filename: '[name].js',
        pathInfo: true
    },
    resolve:
    {
        root: srcPath,
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', srcPath, 'typings']
    },
    module:
    {
        loaders:
        [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory', include: [srcPath], exclude: [serverPath]},
            {test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory', include: [srcPath], exclude: [serverPath] },
            {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader?cacheDirectory', include: [srcPath], exclude: [serverPath] },
            {test: /\.tsx$/, loader: 'ts-loader?cacheDirectory', include: [srcPath], exclude: [serverPath] },
            {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']},
            {test: /\.png$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.jpg$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.jpeg$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
            {test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff"},
            {test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff"},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?mimetype=application/octet-stream"},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader"}
        ]
    },
    plugins:
    [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin
        ([
            { from: path.join(srcPath, 'images'), to: 'images' }
        ]),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('lib', 'lib.js'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin
        ({
            inject: true,
            template: path.join(srcPath, 'index.html')
        }),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Comment: did you ever solved this?

Comment: No, I think I had to move everything into separate folders eventually - i.e. put the webpback config into the client folder

Comment: Thanks. While trying to overcome a build issue, I noticed somehow that include/exclude seem to be more affected by regex than by absolute path string. It might be something I was doing wrong, but it might be worth trying that at a next occasion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62480970/8650621

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried excluding the folder in your `tsconfig.json`?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    ...
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/server",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: had 40 errors, now I got 2000, so it's clearly not working, anyone has a solution for this ?

Comment: Saaame here. Exclude has all the definitions for excluding, but webpack/ts-loader are still trying to compile things within node_modules.