# CopyWebpackPlugin - ignore a folder

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Using CopyWebpackPlugin, I am not able to ignore a specific folder or a specific file. It copies everything.

What I have done in the webpack.config.js:

```
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            from: 'src/assets',
            to: 'assets',
            ignore: ['src/assets/img/folder/test.png']
        },
    ]),
```

I also tried like that:

```
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            from: 'src/assets',
            to: 'assets',
            ignore: ['src/assets/img/folder/*']
        },
    ]),
```

Regarding the [readme](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#ignore) I think I am doing right.

Comment: It does not work because you gave the whole path
ignore: ['test.png'] and for folder ignore: ['folder/*']

Answer (score 20, accepted):

New versions of CopyWebpackPlugin have changed the way of ignoring files.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    patterns: [{
        from: defaultSourcePath,
        globOptions: {
            ignore: [
                '**/css/my.css',
                '**/js/my.js',
                '**/index.html'
            ]
        }
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```js
ignore: ['img/folder/**/*']
```

This will not copy the entire `img/folder`.

> Remember to clear your destination folder before running your webpack.

Answer (score 0):

```
ignore:['img/folder/**/*']
```

Worked to ignore a specific folder & contents with CopyWebpackPlugin.